# How can I convert an German date format with two digits in year to UTC-format?

Tags: c#, datetime

My Problem: I want to convert an german date "24.05.05" to the UTC-Format "2005-05-24". In German date format "24.05.05" the last two digits is the year 2005.

Here is my code which not works:

```
var lGermanDate = "24.05.05";
DateTime lOutDateTime;
CultureInfo lCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-de");

// expecting result to fail
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(lGermanDate, lCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, lCultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out lOutDateTime))
{
    var lTargetDate = lOutDateTime.ToString("yyyy-m-d");
}
else
{
    [...]
}
```

Note: in PHP this works with the following code:

```
\DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y', $lGermanDate )->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: FYI the `m` in date format strings will be replace with the minutes value not the month number, You'll need to use `M`. To make sure both month and day are double digits use `MM` and `dd` respectively.

Comment: Nit: UTC is a time standard and stands for "Coordinated Universal Time".  It is not a "format".  You appear to have meant "ISO 8601 format", or more precisely, "ISO 8601 date-only extended format".

Comment: It is _normal_ that your parsing operation fail because you try to parse `dd.MM.yy` formatted string with `dd.MM.yyyy` format which came from `ShortDatePattern` of the `de-de` culture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try the following?

```
//To Convert lGermanDate into DateTime
string DATEPATTERN = "dd.MM.yy";

DateTime.TryParseExact(lGermanDate, DATEPATTERN, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime outGermanDate);

//From outGermanDate to UTC Format
string dateUTC = outGermanDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parsing is fine, maybe a little too specific

m is minutes is DateTime.ToString() patterns, M is month

```
var germanDateStr = "24.05.05";

    if (DateTime.TryParse(germanDateStr, out DateTime outDateTime))
    {
        var targetDate = outDateTime.ToString("yyyy-M-d");

        targetDate.Dump();
    }
    else
    {

    }
```